# Laravel controller route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

In Laravel 5.1 I was able to create following route:

`Route::controller('posts', 'PostsController');`

It was very handy, since I could use methods depending on request type:

```
public function getCreate()
{
     // method for getting
}

public function postCreate()
{
     // method for creating
}
```

In Laravel 5.5 it appears that this functionality (HTTP Controllers) has been removed(?) and replaced by HTTP Requests.

Requests are nice, but not that handy.. and it offers way more methods than I need.

Is there a possibility to keep using request-related method names for controllers in Laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Resource Route

**Resource Controllers**

Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles all HTTP requests for "photos" stored by your application. Using the make:controller Artisan command, we can quickly create such a controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

This command will generate a controller at `app/Http/Controllers/PhotoController.php`. The controller will contain a method for each of the available resource operations.

Next, you may register a resourceful route to the controller:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a variety of actions on the resource. The generated controller will already have methods stubbed for each of these actions, including notes informing you of the HTTP verbs and URIs they handle.

Actions Handled By Resource Controller

[image]

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Yes, however I don't need all of these actions like destroy or update in my controller. In addition, in a HTTP Controller way action was a controller method name. In a resource controller I can't change method names.

Comment: @Kesse.as per my knowledge i think this is the nly one option .will see if any one have other ideas

Comment: You can add `->only([$etc])` and provide the routes that you want to use (in your case only index and store?

Answer (score 1):

Route::controller() was eliminated after Laravel 5.3

Route::resource() is *very specific* to exactly, only create for you and let you access the seven methods to CRUD an object

If you want to create your own views, I believe you have to define all them with Route::get(), Route::post(), etc. in the routes/web file